# Don't get any errors but no data for following query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Question is: list employee details for the employees who work at the same cinema as the employee Joe Bloggs who has empno 77.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE Cinema_no IN (SELECT Cinema_no 
                    FROM Employee
                    WHERE Forename = 'Joe'
                      AND Surname = 'Bloggs')
  AND Empno <> 77;
```

There are no error messages but it does not return the employees that work at same cinema as Joe Bloggs?

Comment: Thanks Petru Maika.  Can you include the result of what the `IN` clause subquery returns by itself?  Also, if you remove the `and empno <> 77`, does the query return Joe Bloggs record?  Thanks

Comment: do share input sample if you are sharing the query itself n desired output too

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks quite fine. I would recommend to use `empno` instead of `surname`/`forname` to identify the employee.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE 
    Cinema_no IN (SELECT Cinema_no FROM Employee WHERE empno = 77)
    AND empno <> 77;
```

Another solution would be to use a join

```
SELECT emp.*
FROM Employee emp
JOIN ( SELECT Cinema_no FROM Employee WHERE empno = 77) cin on emp.cinema_no = cin.cinema_no
WHERE emp.empno <> 77;
```

Comment: ah yes these worked perfectly thanks.

Surname appears at the end though and not after the first name. Any way to fix this?

Comment: `select *` displays the columns in the order of the table's projection. If you want a different ordering you need to explicitly list the columns in the order you desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from employee 
where cinema_no in (select cimema_no 
                    from employees 
                    where emp_no = 77)
  and emp_no <> 77;
```

Your query was perfectly fine until you had that forename/surname if you want with that here's the below

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE Cinema_no IN (SELECT Cinema_no 
                    FROM Employee
                    WHERE UPPER(FORENAME) = UPPER('Joe')
                      AND UPPER(SURNAME) = UPPER('Bloggs'))
  AND empno <> 77
```